# What's the best practice for iOS StoreKit legacy/upgrade support?

Tags: iphone, ios, upgrade, legacy, storekit

I'm working on an iPhone application that, to date, has used a flat pricing model. In the next version the plan is to reduce the basic feature set and price, then give users the option to make in-app purchases for feature packs.

Adding in-app purchases seems very straight forward. My concern is that it's non-obvious how I should handle legacy support for users who currently own the app because, on upgrade, they should still have access to all of the features. I.e. legacy users should not lose access to features; they should be treated as if they already paid for them.

The simplest way to deal with this, I think, is to have some routine test for the existence of a flag in a plist file (or the NSUserDefaults): if the flag isn't there, it's upgrading from a previous version.

Another would be some callback that's fired when the kernel detects the first launch of an updated version of an application. I can't find much in the available documentation for this kind of support, however.

Can anyone make a recommendation?

---

EDIT: There is also two related scenarios that need to be addressed:

1) User has the old version of the app installed. They upgrade, but later uninstall the app. When they reinstall (the new version from the store) they should still have access to the legacy features.

2) User uninstalled the old version of the app, but decides to install the updated version from the store. As far as the app is concerned, it's a brand new installation.

(1) seems addressable by having the upgrade procedure create a number of $0 purchases in StoreKit. That way, Apple's support for restoring apps (and purchases) should just work.

As for (2), I have no idea if there's any way to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first route (checking for the existence of a plist file value) and it worked for people who were updating but it didn't work for those that had deleted the app and then downloaded and tried to use the update.  (Or if at any point they delete the app and reinstall, they would lose the feature)

Fortunately, I had a mechanism to activate features using a "promo" code, so when a few users complained that they had paid for the previous version but no longer had certain features when they became in app purchases I send them a promo code to reactive the feature.  Not ideal because I had no way to verify that they actually purchased it but only a few even asked.

Comment: I was just considering the problem you mentioned with people deleting the app. Seems to me that one approach is to have the app perform "fake" purchases (for $0) on upgrade so that they can be restored if a user re-installs. That wouldn't work for people who deleted the app and later wanted to try the new version, however. Having a promo code might be a good workaround; thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can't have an In-App purchase that is $0.  The minimum is $0.99 (in the US).